# Trying to embed mp4 in a Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, media9, dimension-expressions

Sample document

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Amsterdam}
\usepackage{media9}

\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\institute{INSTITUTE}
\date{DATE}

\begin{document}

 \addtocounter{framenumber}{1}
 \frame{\titlepage}

 \begin{frame}{Title}
 \includemedia[
  width=\paperwidth,
  height=0.7\linewidth,
   activate=pageopen,
 addresource=C:/Users/David/Desktop/NF/1.mp4,
 flashvars={source=C:/Users/David/Desktop/NF/1.mp4
 &loop=true
 &scaleMode=letterbox
    }
 ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I know this has already been asked. So please before anyone just gets rid of this question, hear me out. I have updated, uninstalled and re-installed MiKTeX2.9 and TeXnicCenter. Hence I do not believe this is an "update packages" fix. I am trying to use the Media9 package to embed a video. (The file format is not relevant I have mp4, avi, & swf of the same video.) I'm a master's student in Mathematics so I use TeX frequently and I've never had such an issue. Every time I compile I get this error

```
You can't use '\dimexpr' in restricted horizontal mode.
<argument> \dimexpr

line 1.28 \end{frame}
```

So my first question is what is this error? Why does it occur and of course how can I resolve it? I read one previously removed question that suggested an update. However, I have tried this. Can anyone suggest something? Am I doing something stupid? I'm not even sure where this "dimension expression" is being used.

Comment: Add first sight, there is no error with your code, though I had to use another theme to compile it, since `Amsterdam` was not found on my system (TL13), and I had to use another file path.

Comment: @AlexG Thank you, I will try a re-install/update again. I suppose there must be something wrong with MiKTeX or the package... Amsterdam is based on the Dresden theme, may I ask what theme you used? Perhaps the issue lies therein the theme.

Comment: I tried with `Dresden`.

Comment: @AlexG Well sadly I have uninstalled and installed MiKTeX2.9/TeXnicCenter twice. I've updated my packages as well as removed and installed `Media9` twice. I cannot get it to compile, gives the same error. Last question I swear, may I ask what you used to compile?

Comment: I used TeXLive-2013 and MiKTeX-2.9, both updated today. No problem with the compilation here.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{C:/Users/David/Desktop/NF} 
\usepackage{media9}
\addmediapath{C:/Users/David/Desktop/NF}

\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\institute{INSTITUTE}
\date{DATE}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \includemedia[
 activate=onclick,
 width=0.75\textwidth
 ]{\includegraphics{Pic.png}}{1.swf}
 \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is progress update. Something very weird that I do not understand. I was able to get the video to embed and play using the above code. However, there is still a caveat... I get the same error about `\dimexpr` along with 23 other errors. If anyone has any suggestions/workarounds I would be very grateful, thank you in advance.

Comment: Weirdly, it compiles for me with the same config you have stated. Maybe it is the slashes backslashes?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code (with \usepackage{media9})

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[ht]
   \movie[width=9.1cm,height=6.5cm,showcontrols=true,loop,poster,text={\small(Loading Video...)}]{}{Safer.avi}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: @R S John Thank you for the comment. It did not work and I believe this is because the control sequence "\movie" is reserved for \usepackage{media15} (outdated) or \usepackage{multimedia}... I'm not sure. However, I could be mistaken, this just gave me an undefined control sequence error. When I use your suggestion and change package to {multimedia} it compiles with a new error. "Package keyval Error: text undefined."